# SQLite for newbies

Tags: c++, sqlite, shared-libraries

It looks like I don't understand something. I decided to use sqlite in my project.
I looked at download page here: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
Thinking that is what I need, developers site.

I thought that I need something like couple of *.dll files and headers for them to use. And maybe some help and "howto" examples.

But I can't find that there. There exists libs (for windows) without headers, or sources without possibility to compile library... and that is oficial site...

Help me find libraries and headers I need to use sqlite in my C++ program under windows? =)

Task is very simple, so it is hard to find similar here, most of people had no problems with that, but I have.

Thank you.

Comment: without possibility to compile library? it's a single C file (when used as library), just include it in your project ...

Comment: but that single C file has no "dllexport" instructions, I searched for "export" word to find, if it contains some functions to export, and didn't found. So I decide, that sqlite3.c is not source of library.

Comment: still that really works somehow, library exports many functions, so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It is so lite that you only need these h and c files